# How to copy HTML content into a new tab

Tags: javascript, php, html, blob

I am building a web app and I need to copy an HTML div and everything inside it into a new tab. I am writing this code in JavaScript. So far I have been working on creating a blob and then creating a file to download. This approach copies all the HTML code I need BUT it does not copy the text that has been inputted into any text fields. As I understand, the problem is that the entered text is not part of the HTML code so it cannot be copied. However I cannot find another approach to this, please assist. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Comment: Once you copied the html, then you'll need loop through all input fields and read their value so you can apply them in the new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Inspired by comment by @vanowm)

First, copy the html (say inside a DIV)

Then you'll need loop through all input fields and read their value so you can apply them.

So the code is like this (amend to suit your further needs):

```
<div id=container><html>
<input type=text name=text1 id="text1">
<br><input type=text name=text2 id="text2">
</html></div>

<textarea id=target style="width:100%;height:200px;"></textarea>

<input type=button name=go onclick="trigger();" value="Parse">

<script>
function trigger(){
target0=document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;

text1= document.getElementById("text1").value;
text2= document.getElementById("text2").value;

target0=target0.replace('id="text1"', 'id="text1" value="' + text1 + '"');
target0=target0.replace('id="text2"', 'id="text2" value="' + text2 + '"');

document.getElementById("target").innerHTML=target0;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) on those elements before [serializing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) your DOM tree. For example:

```js
input.setAttribute("value", input.value)
```

This will copy the mutable value (not serializable) to the attribute (which **is** serializable).

---

Here's a snippet demonstration:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

console.log('initial:', input.outerHTML);

input.value = 'hello world';
console.log('before:', input.outerHTML);

input.setAttribute('value', input.value);
console.log('after:', input.outerHTML);
```

```html
<input type="text">
```